# Пвсевдокласс hover в JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Здравствуйте, возникла проблема с тем, что при клике на элемент, у меня у другого элемента должно быть постоянное выделение, т.е. (:hover) в css. Использовать вместо этого  $("...").css(...) и перечислять стили которые должны быть при наведении на элемента. Мне нужна именно ф-ия, если такая имеется, чтобы элемент был постоянно в режиме выделения

Comment: Класс навешивайте, при чем тут ховер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример кода:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("элемент №1").hover(function() {
            jQuery('элемент #2').addClass( "твой класс" );
        },function(){
            jQuery('элемент #2').removeClass( "твой класс" );
        });         
    });
```

В классе описываешь стили hover.
Вторым параметров в jQuery.hover() передается функция которая сработает при unhover.